# Is OO Base compatible with MSO Access?

Tags: ms-access, openoffice-base

Is Open Office Base compatible with MS Office Access? That is, can I successfully edit an Access-made database from Base?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By opening oo base (version 3.3), the dialog box proposes to select a database and connect to an existing one. Among the available options, it is possible to connect directly to:

- an Acces Database
- an Access 2007 Database
- an ODBC database
- an ADO database

Though the "Acces Specific" connectors will allow you to transfer existing data from an Access database to a ooBase database, the more generic one (ODBC, ADO) can allow you to manipulate any ODBC\ADO compatible database, including Access. Though it is dated, you could refer to this [oo version2](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/817-6341) document, where there is an example of connecting from ooBase to Access through ADO

Comment: So I understand I _cannot_ really edit an Access db and keep the structure the same, so that I can use it in Access again normally (including queries, reports etc.)?

Comment: Only the data and queries would be accessible. UI objects would not be (forms/reports/modules/macros).

Comment: You can use DDL (Data Definition Language) to update an Access database through an ADO or ODBC connection. Of course, only objects available through such connections (ie tables and queries) are updatable. As noticed by David, specific Access objects such as forms, reports, macros, cannot be modified.

Comment: Ok, since I'm a beginner, how do I actually use DDL and these connections? From somewhere within OOBase or...? The only things I need to edit actually are tables and queries.

Comment: Do you need to edit the structure of the tables/queries, or just the data returned by them?

Comment: Well you are here trying to solve other problems, such as (1) how to open an ODBC\ADO connection and (2) how to send a SQL instruction through an ODBC\ADO connection ...

Comment: I just need to edit the data, plain simple, without SQL queries as such. I'd like to just edit queries and I'll run them in Access.

Comment: Do you have any experience of similar tasks (opening a connection, creating a set of records, sending query on a database) with other languages (VB, java, ...) and databases (MS-SQL, MySQL, etc)?

Comment: I have some experience with SQL Server from C# that includes ADO. But I still don't understand how is that connected to what I need to do?